# The 'right' way to express the line element $ds^2$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Taking Minkowski space as an example, the line element is commonly expressed as,

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - dx^2-dy^2-dz^2.$$

However, when expressing the line element in terms of an orthonormal basis $e^a$ it may be expressed as,

$$ds^2 = e^t \otimes e^t - e^x \otimes e^x - e^y \otimes e^y - e^z \otimes e^z.$$

In the case of Minkowski space, we of course have $e^t = dt$ and so forth. This then makes me question whether in the first line element $dt$ is somehow different from the $e^t = dt$ since there is no tensor product symbol. As I understand it, $e^t$ is a differential form and so lives in a section of the cotangent bundle of the underlying manifold.

What's the correct way to express the line element?

Comment: No, $ds \otimes ds =dt \otimes dt- dx \otimes dx - dy \otimes dy - dz \otimes dz$ is also a perfectly valid way of writing it, in fact this is the more formally correct way, the usual one is an abbreviation. Sometimes symmetric tensor product is used instead of  $\otimes$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An (orthonormal) basis $e_a$ is *not* a collection of differential forms, but a collection of vector fields. One would denote its dual basis (of the differential 1-forms) by differential forms $\theta^a$ if it is a non-coordinate basis and by something like $\mathrm{d}x^a$ if it is a coordinate basis. The dual basis is defined by $\theta^a(e_b) = \delta^a_b$.
2. The metric is canonically defined as a 2-tensor acting on vector fields, i.e. for a basis of *differential 1-forms* $\theta^a$ it has components
   $$ g = g_{ij}(\theta^i\otimes\theta^j).$$
   In case of a coordinate basis, 
   $$ g = g_{ij}(\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^j)$$
   and by convention one often writes $(\mathrm{d}x^i)^2$ for $\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^i$. For the Minkowski metric and the standard coordinate basis this clearly reproduces your first formula.
3. In general, there is no orthonormal coordinate basis (this would mean you're in flat space). However, non-coordinate bases can often be found that are orthonormal. Suppose you have such an $e_a$ with a dual basis $\theta^a$. Since an orthonormal basis has $g(e_a,e_b) = \eta_{ab}$, where $\eta = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ is the usual Minkowski metric, you have that $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab}$ in the dual basis, i.e.
   $$ g = \theta^1\otimes\theta^1 - \sum_{i=2}^4 \theta^i\otimes\theta^i,$$
   which reproduces your second formula.

Note that all of these manipulations require careful consideration what geometric object you are dealing with: The vector fields $e_a$ are different from the differential forms $\theta^a$, and writing $g = e_a\otimes e_a$ would be non-sensical - the metric tensor by definition is a tensor acting on vectors, not a tensor made as the tensor product of vector acting on differential forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the question but with regards to defining a line element $(ds)^2$ in terms of basis vectors we have the relation $g_{ij}=\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{e}_j$ so the line element is given by

$$ (ds)^2  = g_{ij} dx^i dx^j = (\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{e}_j )dx^i dx^j$$